# Droplist has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

First I would like to state that I am using a Datatable to fill my gridview and the select that I am using is a left join. here is a my `select`

```
SELECT PM.num [num], PMT.MedType [MedType], 
...Some other columns...
FROM [pharm_meds] PM 
LEFT JOIN [pharm_meds_Type] PMT ON  PM.[MedType_ID] = PMT.[num]
```

and I am being lazy and currently have a `asp:DropDownList` being filled by a sqldatasource located outside the gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "75px"  HeaderText = "Med Type">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMedType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MedType")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedType" DataSourceID="sdsMedType" DataTextField="MedType" DataValueField="MedType" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("num") %>' Text='<%# Bind("num") %>' runat="server">

            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>  
        <FooterTemplate>               
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedType" DataSourceID="sdsMedType" DataTextField="MedType" DataValueField="MedType" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("num") %>' Text='<%# Bind("num") %>' runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" >

            </asp:DropDownList>
        </FooterTemplate> 
        <ItemStyle Width="75px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

here is the  sqldatasource for the `asp:DropDownList`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMedType" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [num], [MedType] FROM [pharm_meds_Type]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now the trouble I have occurs when I want to edit the existing rows here is my code for it

```
protected void EditMedication(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlMedType = (DropDownList)gvMainView.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlMedType");
        string strMedID = ddlMedType.Text;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer2"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [num], [MedType] from [pharm_meds_Type] where [MedType] = @MedID", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedID", strMedID);
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader1.Read())
                {
                    MyMedType = reader1.GetInt32(0);
                }
                ddlMedType.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(MyMedType); //failed attempt to fix the issue
                gvMainView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
                BindData();
            }
        }

    }
```

When I hit the edit link I get the error in the title. How do I fix this?

Comment: The out-of-the-box `dropdownlist` is a horrible and unfriendly control.  I would suggest that you `.Clear()`, `SelectedIndex = -1` and `SelectedValue = null` (or, `SelectedValue = 0`) _before_ you populate the control.  OR, you could create a user control and use that instead.

Comment: Do you have values in the "num" column of the pharm_meds table that are not in the "num" column of the pharm_meds_Type table?  It seems to me like that would cause this error to crop up for you.

Answer (score 0):

One reason this error appears is because your SQL Table that the dropdownlist writes to has a value that isn't contained in the dropdownlist values.  One of the more common errors are a difference in numbers and decimals.  For example, 0.8 and 0.800 are two different numbers in dropdownlists.  If the first decimal value is part of the dropdownlist options and you have 0.800 in the column that the dropdownlist writes to, it will throw that error.

Basically, if you have a specific value in the column that the dropdownlist writes to and it is not part of the dropdownlist, this error will get thrown.

To fix it you'll have to remove the dropdownlist, edit the gridview, and make sure all the values in the database are the same.  Either that or edit the database manually.